# how to create a derived table from two other tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 base tables TABLE_1 and TABLE_2. i want to derive a new table consisting ID of both table.

I NEED SQL QUERY TO CREATE THE THIRD TABLE CALLED NEW_TABLE in which ID_1 and ID_2 combines to form primary key. and if any of the ID in TABLE_1 or TABLE_2 is updated or deleted it should be reflected in NEW_TABLE also.
eg:

```
TABLE_1          TABLE_2
ID    XXX        ID     ZZZ
100   A          200     P
101   B          201     Q  
102   N          202     R 
103   F          203     S

NEW_TABLE
ID_1   ID_2
100    200
100    201
100    203
101    200
101    202
103    200
103    201
103    203
```

PLEASE HELP ME......thanks in advance..:-)

Comment: perhaps what you want is a view? www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: what do the datasets in the two different tables have in common? i see no condition on which the datasets can be joined together. I'm sure you dont want random results!

Answer (score 2):

You can use SELECT INTO to select from some table(s) and insert the data into a new table.

Comment: I do agree that you probably want to use a view, though.  If you definitely want to create a table then this is the easiest way to do it, but in your case you do likely want a view.

Answer (score 1):

you can use views for above case

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to use a view

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use just a query instead of table

```
SELECT
TABLE_1.ID,TABLE_2.ID
FROM TABLE_1,TABLE_2
```